# How to find the integral of the following function step by step.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find the following integral?

I tried to substitute $\sin (\theta)$ with $z$ but couldn't quite get to final steps.

Any solution or tips will be helpful.

$$\int(\sin \Theta+\cos \Theta+\sqrt{\sin 2 \Theta})^{2} d \Theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand out:

$$\int \left( \sin ^2(\theta )+\sin (2 \theta )+2 \sin (\theta ) \sqrt{\sin (2 \theta )}+\cos ^2(\theta
   )+2 \sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta )+2 \sqrt{\sin (2 \theta )} \cos (\theta ) \right)d\theta$$

$$= \theta +\sin (\theta ) \sqrt{\sin (2 \theta )}-\cos (2 \theta )-\sin ^{-1}(\cos (\theta
   )-\sin (\theta ))-\sqrt{\sin (2 \theta )} \cos (\theta )$$